# How to open drawer in react native using navigation.openDrawer()

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-drawer, react-native-drawer

I wanted to create a burger icon to open drawer but has been unable to do so. I have included the icon button on the right of my header. Whenever I click it to open the drawer, it shows the error of undefined function. I have mentioned the error below.

TypeError: navigation.openDrawer is not a function. (In 'navigation.openDrawer()', 'navigation.openDrawer' is undefined)

This is App.js, in this I have mentioned the code for drawer using createDrawerNavigator()

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

import PassengerScreen from './Passenger';
import Lovedones from './Lovedones';
import NewTab from './FirstScreen';


import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default App=() => ( 
<NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Passenger" drawerPosition="right" > 
        <Drawer.Screen name="Passenger" component={PassengerScreen} options= {{ title:'Passenger'}} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Lovedones" component={Lovedones} options= {{ title:'loved ones!!'}} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="New Screen" component={NewTab}  />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

This is AccountScreen.js, in this code, I have created the icon button to open the drawer using navigation.openDrawer()

**AccountScreen.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';


const Stack= createStackNavigator();

Account = () => {
  return <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Hello!!</Text>
  </View>
};
export default AccountStack =(navigation)=>(
          <Stack.Navigator >
            <Stack.Screen name="Account" component= {Account} options={{headerRight: () => (<Ionicons.Button name="reorder-three" color={"#FF0000"} size={40} backgroundColor= {"none"} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}/> )  }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Kindly help me in identifying the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line
`export default AccountStack =(navigation)=>`.

Here your navigation variable points to the **props** instead of **props.navigation**.

To fix this you should destructure your navigation object from the props and change this line to

`export default AccountStack =({navigation})=>`